# When will we have SnapChat and KIK apps in windows phone store ?

Tags: apps, store

I use Microsoft LUMIA 540. The only chatting app which I could use in it is Whatsapp. When will it support apps like snapchat, kik. There is also an KIK app in store which will never installs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because only the app developers know if and when an app will be released for Windows Phone.

Comment: Thomas is correct; this is off-topic here. However, your last sentence sounds as if you're having a problem with the app installing. If so, that is definitely on topic and could be posted as a separate question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [petition](https://www.change.org/p/snapchat-make-snapchat-available-for-windows-phone) for Snapchat which has over 57k signatures. So there's a pressure. Other than that it's impossible to answer your question due to the fact that both companies haven't made an official announcement regarding the matter. Let's hope soon.

Comment: If you think that I provided the correct answer, please mark it accordingly.

Comment: You have answered my question partially. I asked about KIK too.